# Show that $\mathcal{l}^2$ has a schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Show that $\mathcal{l}^2$ has a schauder basis. To do so we can take $(e_n) = ( 0,..,1,..,0)$ where $1$ is in the $nth$ position. Let $x \in \mathcal{l}^2$ and then for all $n$ we have $x- \sum_{k=1}^n x_ke_k = (0,....,0,x_{n+1}...)$ and so we obtain $$ \|x - \sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k \|^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |x_k|^2 \to 0$$

It remains to show that $(x_k)$ is unique, so we choose another sequence $(y_k) \in \mathcal{l}^2$. Then we have $$\|x- \sum_{k=1}^n y_ke_k \|^2$$

however, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know that if we can show that this new term doesn't converge to $0$ then we have shown that $(x_k)$ is unique. I was hoping to get some tips on where to take this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $j$ and $n >j$ we have $0\leq (x_j-y_j)^{2} \leq  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-y_k)^{2}=\ \|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (x_ke_k-y_ke_k)\|^{2}  \to 0$.